# How to make "gtk.gdk.pixbuf_new_from_file()" use a relative path?

Tags: python, pygtk

In `gtk.gdk.pixbuf_new_from_file(image)`, if "image" is not an absolute path, I get:

```
glib.GError: Failed to open file 'image.png': No such file or directory
```

That's unless I'm in the directory where the image lives.

**note1**: I'm running [Debian Squeeze](http://www.debian.org/releases/squeeze/), which uses Python 2.6 by default.
**note2**: The image and the script live in one directory.

Comment: Could you give some additional information about the execution environment (Python version, operating system, etc.)?

Comment: What's wrong with `os.path.join()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not specific to `pixbuf_new_from_file`, relative paths are always resolved relative to the current directory, which initially is the directory the script is started from.

You can get the directory the script is actually in with `os.path.dirname(__file__)`. Then you can either make it your script's current directory with `os.chdir`, or you can use `os.path.join` to combine it with `image.png`.